# Add JSON to Nested JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a table created using ng-repeat for rows and columns.

```
ng-model="tableValues[row][column]"
```

Here row and column values come from ng-repeat. The table data is dropdowns. I want to populate this data from list of values;

While writing values to the ng-model from the controller it is overwriting values for columns.

```
var x ={};
for(objData){
        row = objData[i]["row"];
        column = objData[i]["column"];
        value = objData[i]["value"];
        x[row]={};
        x[row][column]=value;
        vm.tableValues=x;
}
```

//objData is an array of objects with each object containing the value and it's corresponding row and column.

This is creating the correct JSON but overwriting values for columns.

```
{"r1":{"c1":"v1"},"r2":{"c2":"v2"},"r3":{"c2":"v2"}}
```

what I want

```
{"r1":{"c1":"v1","c2":"v2","c3":v3,"c4":"v4"},
{"r2":{"c1":"v1","c2":"v2","c3":v3,"c4":"v4"}.......} 
so forth..
```

Rather than putting all column values inside of a row JSON by comma, it overwrites the previous column values.

Comment: Loop over rows and colums. You are getting this result because you are looping over rows array only. or paste your code for loop here

Comment: the loop is for a list of objects that has the row , column and value in each object. can you help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce on both the rows and colums:

```js
var rows = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5'];
var columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'];
var values = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'];

let res = rows.reduce((p, k) => {
  p[k] = columns.reduce((a, b, i) => {
    a[b] = values[i] || "no value";
    return a;
  }, {});
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. What when the length & column array are not the same. I've edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: @Api I don't see explanation on what should happen then in your question, but I edited my answer to return a default value in case of no match in the values array.

Comment: my number of column values are not same as values. Can you please look at my question again i've updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var x ={};
    var rows=["r1","r2","r3","r4","r5"]
        var columns=["c1","c2","c3"]
        var values = ["v1","v2","v3"]
        
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<columns.length;j++){
        if(!x[rows[i]])
           x[rows[i]]={};
        x[rows[i]][columns[j]]=values[j] || "no data";
      } 
    }
    console.log(x);
```

Comment: Does not work with my problem, kindly look at my question edited to reflect the situation more precisely.